# Getting a time from a text file

Tags: java, arraylist

So far I have put the text file into a list array and have been able to search for the current day. But I cannot find a way to get a time range out of the text file.

Text File

```
Jack Johnson
Thursday 07:00 17:45,
```

Is there any way to get these time values out of the text file and compare the current time to check if it falls between these 2 time values. I have already got the current time but I just cannot figure out how to get these 2 time values out of the text file

```
Boolean isAvail = false;
Date day = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
String token1 = "";

Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("E:\\Folder\\text.txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*");

List<String> availability = new ArrayList<String>();

while (inFile1.hasNext()) 
{
    token1 = inFile1.next();
    availability.add(token1);
}
inFile1.close();


String[] availabilityArray = availability.toArray(new String[0]);

String searchArray = simpleDateformat.format(day);
for (String curVal : availabilityArray)
{
    if (curVal.contains(searchArray))
    {
    System.out.println(curVal);
    }
}

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(dtf.format(now));
```

Comment: Why don't you show us your code so far?

Comment: you need to use `regular expression` to extract these values

Comment: You can check if the current character you are on during iteration is an integer. If it is, using the index of the iterator you can extract the times using substring from this index until the final integer. Sorry I'm on my phone, hope I understood the question properly.

Comment: Update the ArrayList data here...

Comment: added my code so far there. Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Is this the complete file structure and does the file structure always stay the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can snatch the string then you can use LocalTime.parse().

```
// Say you got that from the file
String timeStart = "07:00";
String timeEnd = "17:45";

// Then
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(timeStart);
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse(timeEnd);
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
if (now.isAfter(start) && now.isBefore(stop)) {
    // whatnot
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old functions, that can parse maintaining a running position:

```
    String input = "Thursday 07:00 17:45,";

    SimpleDateFormat weekdayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.US);
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    Date wd = weekdayFormat.parse(input, pos);
    System.out.println("wd " + wd);

    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US);
    Date from = timeFormat.parse(input, pos);
    Date to = timeFormat.parse(input, pos);
    System.out.println("" + from + " - " + to);
```

The result being a bit of unused fields.

```
wd Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 1970
Thu Jan 01 07:00:00 CET 1970 - Thu Jan 01 17:45:00 CET 1970
```

With `Date.toInstant()` or whatever one can convert them to new time types, like LocalTime.

---

***New time API:***

```
    String input = "Thursday 07:00 17:45,";

    DateTimeFormatter weekdayFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", Locale.US);
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    TemporalAccessor wd = weekdayFormat.parse(input, pos);
    System.out.println("wd " + wd);

    DateTimeFormatter timeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(" HH:mm", Locale.US);
    TemporalAccessor from = timeFormat.parse(input, pos);
    TemporalAccessor to = timeFormat.parse(input, pos);
    System.out.println("" + from + " - " + to);
```

Giving

```
wd {DayOfWeek=4},ISO
{},ISO resolved to 07:00 - {},ISO resolved to 17:45
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8, you can use the `LocalTime` class for the times and extract the time values from the file using `regex`. For example using the string you provided as input you can do this:

```
    String stringWithTime = "Jack Johnson Thursday 07:00 17:45,";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\s(\\d{2}:\\d{2})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(stringWithTime);

    while(m.find()) {
        LocalTime firstTime = LocalTime.parse(m.group(1));
        LocalTime secondTime = LocalTime.parse(m.group(2));

        LocalTime nowTime = LocalTime.now();

        boolean isBetween = firstTime.isBefore(nowTime) && secondTime.isAfter(nowTime);
    }
```